# Ubuntu 18.04 programs not responding after a period of time

Tags: xps

I have bought a new computer (Dell XPS 13) with Ubuntu 18.04 and my problem is that after a period of time I can not open any program. Google Chrome quit after execution, the text editor is freezed and the terminal shows no response. When I try to shutdown the computer it is freezed in a black screen with a blinking white line in the top left corner of the screen. The only way out of it is to force the computer to shutdown with the power button.

Comment: Is it the same after the reboot?
Has anything changed recently? Were there any new updates applied?

Comment: After the reboot it is all fine but after a period of time this problem occurs. I have bought this computer two weeks ago and installed some software (VSCode, Gimp etc.). Furthermore I have activate the hibernate mode for Ubuntu.